# count the occurence of a specific character of a file in haskell

Tags: haskell

I am a beginner with haskell and i wonder how i can count the characters in a file in haskell. From [this book](https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=olp7lAtpRX0C&pg=PA42&lpg=PA42&dq=how%20to%20count%20the%20characters%20in%20a%20string%20in%20haskell&source=bl&ots=IxJWhB8y62&sig=NaSzRnITy2NUAsVWV77-XDKUjhU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjU1s-WneHJAhUFDywKHfu9AR4Q6AEIRzAG#v=onepage&q=how%20to%20count%20the%20characters%20in%20a%20string%20in%20haskell&f=false) i wrote the count of any character in any string, but i wonder if i can do the same function with files. The code is similar like following;

```
count :: Char -> String -> Int 
count x xs = length [x'|x'<-xs, x==x']
```

Any help would be very great. Thanks!

Edit: I am very new to haskell so this may be a very stupid question :)

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878065/get-size-of-file-in-haskell

Comment: i am not trying to find the size. I am trying to find the occurence of specific characters.

Comment: oh ok. first you should change the signature. `I/O` is not a type, it's a syntax error. the signature should be something like `countChars :: Char -> String -> Int`

Comment: oh yes it was like that i am sorry i posted the wrong code segment,i was trying. It was the same with yours.

Comment: you should edit your question then. as it is written now, it doesn't even compile

Comment: Okey i did thanks for warning

Comment: `\chr fp -> length . filter (==chr) <$> readFile fp`

Comment: I want to find all the 's' so will the code be like this?

\s /tmp/foo.txt -> length.filter(==s)<$> readFile tmp/foo.txt

Comment: do you know how to read in the contents of a file? do you know how to do monadic binding? => read contents of file into a variable, e.g. `s` => calculate `count 'x' s`

Comment: I think the `<$>` function is too advanced for you yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reusing your `count` function. You can map it over a `readFile` with returns you a file's content as a string:

```
count :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
count x xs = length [x' | x' <- xs, x==x']

cntFile :: Char -> FilePath -> IO Int
cntFile c f = count c <$> readFile f

main :: IO ()
main = do
    cnt <- cntFile 'c' "test.hs"
    print cnt
```

The operator `<$>` is just the infix notation for `fmap`, which does to `IO` and any other `Functor` what `map` does to lists.

The longer alternative for beginner would probably be:

```
cntFile' :: Char -> FilePath -> IO Int
cntFile' c f = do
    content <- readFile f
    let cnt = count c content
    return cnt
```

Comment: That was a great explanation for my question. Thank you so much :)